# Equating polynomials that are exactly identical

Tags: polynomials

There's this question in my textbook:

> [image]

How do I go about this question?

Comment: We need to find a, b and c.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients

Comment: Expand the left hand side and tidy up

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT

You need to find simple equations for $a,b,c$.

There are two main methods that you can try.

1. Substitute values for $x$. For example, what do you get if you let $x=0$?
2. Multiply out the LHS and collect up all the $x^2$ terms, the $x$ terms and the constant terms. Then equate the number of each with the numbers on the RHS.

You might like to try this and add what you find to your post.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: I have suggested how the post can be improved. "You might like to try this and add what you find to your post."

Comment: You shouldn't have answered it at all. Those suggestions need to be in the comments